# Meaning of ものはないか

Tags: meaning

Context: the character is in a store, searching for something fun to do.

Full sentence: 俺は何か面白いものはないか、店内を見回してみた。

My question is about the first part of the sentence, "俺は何か面白いものはないか", specifically about "ものはないか".

The character seems to be talking something on the lines of:

"Is there something of interest for me?"

From my understanding, もの here is used here to mean thing/object, so "something that is 面白い", but I'm not sure about the はないか part of the sentence, is the は a particle? If so, why is there two in the same sentence, since we have "俺は" already.
If not, is **「はないか」** a expression with it's own meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bold part of the sentence is actually an embedded question which modifies the verb 見回してみた.

> 俺は、**何か面白いものはないか**、店内を見回してみた。
>
> I looked around the store, checking whether there is any interesting stuff.

Yes, もの refers to a physical object. はないか is broken down into は+ない+か. は here can be understood as a contrast marker. He is looking for interesting stuff, as opposed to uninteresting stuff.